# Short Ciruit a Servlet Filter chain when the web.xml catches the top-level url-pattern

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I have tried to piece together what I have read here and nothing seems to work for me.  I am trying to redirect the user to an error .jsp page when they don't have access to my server.  So I have the standard Java `Filter`.
Note, I'll be terse where it doesn't matter too much.

```
public class SecurityFilter implement Filter
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse resp, final FilterChain chain) {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
    if (user has access) {
       write to DAO
    }
    else {
       HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)resp;
       response.reset();
       response.setContentType("text/plain");
       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
       response.setHeader("Location", request.getRequestURL.toString());
       Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
       for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
          response.addCookie(cookie);
       }
       request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
       return;
   }
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Now my `web.xml` file looks like the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>securityCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ui.filter.SecurityCheckFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

...

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>securityCheckFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My problem is, I have an `index.jsp` file which loads up many others at different urls.  When it gets hit the security filter gets hit a number of times.  I thought the `return` statement would stop the chain but it doesn't.  I can't name the filter because I have only one filter class.  How can I stop processing once access has been denied?

Comment: Looks ok to me, I suspect your problem is in the `if (user has access)` logic

Comment: Are you sure its going to else block ?

Comment: Yeah, I have a TON of logs in both the `else` and `if` blocks which print out the cookies, URL, if it's redirected, when it's about to redirect, etc.

Comment: @NickJ - yeah, like I said before, the `if (user has access)` is just really terse, i.e. not really relevant - it's just a boolean statement.

Comment: So you meant to say even after hitting the `error.jsp` control is going to the filter ?

Comment: @Rehman I don't know.  Sometimes error.jsp will display but regardless, the console spits "ACCESS DENIED" for each of the 20 original .jsp files that caused the security failure.

Comment: Ok, now I know when the `error.jsp` is displayed.  When I set the status to `SC_FOUND` I get a redirection error.  When I set the status to a 401, then the `error.jsp` gets displayed.  I use the `request.getRequestURL()` to set the `"Location"` and when I use `SC_FOUND` I only get the server name, when I use 401 I get the full file name of the request.  Don't know why that is.

Comment: Did you try placing the chain line(chain.doFilter(request, response);)  within the if block(after the write to DAO) ?

Comment: @rickz Just gave that a shot, didn't make a difference.